# Custom @Scheduled Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a method `doJob()` runs at every 10 seconds like below.
I want to customize the running period at run time. I mean , between 2pm-3pm `doJob()` runs every 5 seconds. between 3pm-4pm `doJob()` runs at every 50 seconds.

Is is possible to customize running period at run time?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    public void doJob() {
}
```

In this article  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

```
Note that some scheduling requirements are too complicated to express with a single trigger - such as "every 5 minutes between 9:00 am and 10:00 am, and every 20 minutes between 1:00 pm and 10:00 pm". The solution in this scenario is to simply create two triggers, and register both of them to run the same job.
```

Comment: interesting question. you can initialize running period from runtime but it is once for application start. You can initialize it from ENV variable, properties file etc... but I think you cannot change it runtime. How do you think to make two cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the same jobs but certainly two different jobs

Job 1 (between 2pm-3pm runs every 5 seconds)

```
0/5 * 2-3 * * ?
```

Job 2 (between 3pm-4pm runs at every 50 seconds)

```
0/50 * 3-4 * * ?
```

Comment: so what is the exact solution. Can you give a sample code portion